# Find a rotation matrix to minimize the maximum distance between matched points

Tags: matrices, optimization

If I have 2 sets of 3D points that are matched so point 1 in set 1 is matched with point 1 in set 2. How can I determine the rotation matrix such that the maximum distance between matched points is minimized? This is similar to using Kabsch to minimize RMSD but instead of minimizing the average distance between points I want to minimize that maximum distance between points.

Comment: Welcome! Please add context and show attempt.

Comment: Thanks. The context is that I have 2 conformers of the same molecule with 3D coordinates and I am trying to align them such that the differences are spread across the alignment as opposed to some atoms being perfectly aligned and one pair being far apart.

Answer (score 0):

Given two indexed data sets $P=\{p_k\}$ and $Q=\{q_k\}$ in which $Q$ is obtained from $P$ thru a translation and a rigid rotation, we can formulate an error measure as

$$
E(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,o)=\sum_k\|q_k-o -R(\alpha,\beta,\gamma).(p_k-o)\|^2
$$

in which $R(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ represents an Euler rotation and $o$ the translation. Now solving the minimization problem

$$
\min_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma,o}E(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,o)
$$

we can find the sought parameters $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,o$. Here $E$ is multi-modal so is indicated an evolutive optimization method.

NOTE

Using an evolutive formulation we can handle easily also the error given as

$$
E(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,o)=\max_k\|q_k-o -R(\alpha,\beta,\gamma).(p_k-o)\|
$$

Attached a MATHEMATICA script showing how to apply this minimization procedure in an hypothetical case

```
R = EulerMatrix[{a, b, c}];
n = 8;
r = 0.4;
dr = 0.2;
Mola = {};
SeedRandom[2]
For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, AppendTo[Mola, {RandomReal[{-1, 1}], i, RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}]]
R0 = R /. {a -> Pi/5, b -> Pi/3, c -> Pi/8};
Molb = Transpose[R0.Transpose[Mola]];
Molb = Table[Molb[[k]] + RandomReal[{-dr, dr}, 3], {k, 1, n}];

(** BEFORE MATCHING **)
gra = Table[Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[Mola[[k]], r]}], {k, 1, n}];
axa = Graphics3D[Line[Mola]];
grb = Table[Graphics3D[{Blue, Sphere[Molb[[k]], r]}], {k, 1, n}];
axb = Graphics3D[Line[Molb]];
Show[gra, axa, grb, axb]
```

[image]

```
o = {ox, oy, oz};
atrans = Table[Mola[[k]] - o, {k, 1, n}];
btrans = Table[Molb[[k]] - o, {k, 1, n}];
error = atrans - Transpose[R.Transpose[btrans]];
obj = Max[Map[Norm, error]];

sol = NMinimize[obj, {a, b, c, ox, oy, oz}, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]

(** AFTER MATCHING **)
a0 = atrans /. sol[[2]];
b0 = Transpose[R.Transpose[btrans]] /. sol[[2]];
gra = Table[Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[a0[[k]], r]}], {k, 1, n}];
axa = Graphics3D[Line[a0]];
grb = Table[Graphics3D[{Blue, Sphere[b0[[k]], r]}], {k, 1, n}];
axb = Graphics3D[Line[b0]];
Show[gra, axa, grb, axb]
```

[image]